# Proving $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n}$ converges if the partial sum $\sum_{n=1}^N a_n$ is bounded by $MN^r$ for some $r<1$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Need to prove that $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{a_n}{n}$ converges when given that the partial sum $A_n:=\sum_{i=1}^n a_i$ satisfies $|A_n|<Mn^r \forall n=1,2,...$ for some $M>0,  r<1$

What I tried:
Dirichlet test with $\frac{a_n}{n}=\frac{a_n}{n^r}\frac{1}{n^(1-r)}$ but could not prove that $\sum_{n=1}^N\frac{a_n}{n^r}$ is bounded $\forall N$.

What method will work?

Thank you,
Jon

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Using summation by parts
$$
\sum\limits_{n = 1}^N {\frac{{a_n }}{n}}  = \frac{A_N}{N} + \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{N - 1} {\frac{A_n}{{n(n + 1)}} } .
$$